# Continue train CNN with saved model in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I train CNN model with keras library with numbers of epoch is 25. Can I run model in first time with 10 epochs then save model with these lines of code:

```
model.fit_generator(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = 100000,
                     epochs = 10,
                     validation_data = test_set,
                     validation_steps = 40000)
from keras.models import load_model
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Then I restart python and continue to run the next 15 epochs with the same dataset like the code bellow:

```
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
model.fit_generator(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = 100000,
                     epochs = 15,
                     validation_data = test_set,
                     validation_steps = 40000)
```

Is it sufficient to continue training ? Or I have to do any other step to continue the job. I am very appreciated with any support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is okay, `model.save` saves the weights, model architecture, and optimizer state, so you can resume training with no problems.

Comment: Thank you, I scare that model will begin to train from very beginning after I restart python. I really appreciated for your support.